# does neo4j really require big RAM size for large set of data?

Tags: performance, neo4j

Current data what we have is node store has almost 65MB of data, and 260MB of relationship store ?

And while going to production, expect 200 users using the application concurrently, which behind the scenes trigger neo4j queries. And I went through the neo4j calculator, it is recommended to have 64G RAM.

Currently the staging where I test has 3 RHEL servers with 8G memory each, and 4G has been assigned for java heap. And it has HDD not SSD. And each server 2 cpu cores.

And as a single user, the simple queries brings the fast, and some complex ones which has to run bigger data nodes run in 20 seconds. It goes well till 2 to 3 users. But after sometime, the results are not returned, and the query runs indeterminately.

I am not sure what is the expected system configuration for the kind of data, and the management wants to justify the requirement for higher system procurement.

Is there any chance, this configuration can be tweaked to support production load.

And I already did the performance tweaks as suggested in the neo4j site, from linux performance to memory cache performance parameters.

Or is it necessary to have bigger RAM to load all relationship into memory, to make the queries and concurrent loads have faster response

---

Query which is in Question

```
match (c:company) 
where c.company IN [ "GENERAL ELECTRIC-TELEPRESENCE","PNOC_REG02","testzenos2","testzenos3","PT10","CMSP_SLT_SYNC","CMSP_SLT_SYNC_2","Smoke Test Company","PTrans-Regr","SPWIFI-POC","PNOC_REG01","IBM","MERAKISP-MERAKICUST","0101rms","Meraki_SP01-new3" ] 

match (c)-[r1]->(s:physical_location)-[r5]->(im:im_tkt) 
where ( 
   ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000259" ] and im.company = "GENERAL ELECTRIC-TELEPRESENCE") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000259" ] and im.company = "PNOC_REG02") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000259","SGP000000000175" ] and im.company = "testzenos2") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000259","SGP000000000175" ] and im.company = "testzenos3") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000259","SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "PT10") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000175","SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "CMSP_SLT_SYNC") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000175","SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "CMSP_SLT_SYNC_2") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "Smoke Test Company") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "PTrans-Regr") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "SPWIFI-POC") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "PNOC_REG01") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "IBM") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "MERAKISP-MERAKICUST") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "0101rms") 
OR ( im.assigned_group_id IN [ "SGP000000000088" ] and im.company = "Meraki_SP01-new3") ) 

RETURN collect(distinct(im.incident_number)) as im_tkt__incident_number , 
       collect(distinct(im.company)) as im_tkt__company , 
       collect(distinct(im.assigned_support_organization)) as im_tkt__assigned_support_organization , 
       collect(distinct(im.assignee)) as im_tkt__assignee , 
       collect(distinct(im.description)) as im_tkt__description , 
       collect(distinct(im.priority)) as im_tkt__priority , 
       collect(distinct(im.status)) as im_tkt__status , 
       collect(distinct(im.impact)) as im_tkt__impact , 
       collect(distinct(im.entryid_TS1)) as im_tkt__entryid_TS1;
```

This is the query which runs for a longer time

---

Comment: Perhaps you can share your data model + queries. SSD would be a great plus. Your store is tiny, so it should be no problem.

Comment: Neo4j version is 2.1.6 enterprise, and added the query in the question. Basically company is related to a site, site related to a device, device is related to alarm or im_tkt.    If an user logins to the application, he need to see all these data in nodes company,site,device,alarm,im based on the company and the im he is entitled to

Comment: did you profile the query? what does your :schema indexes and constraints look like? If you send an email to neo4j.com/contact-us we can help you also sort it out 1:1

Answer (score 0):

Did you create indexes or constraints ?

```
create index on :company(company);
create index on :im_tkt(assigned_group_id);
```

Use Parameters in your real program !!

Pass in a list of maps for param like this:

```
[{company:"GENERAL ELECTRIC-TELEPRESENCE", 
  assigned_group_ids:[ "SGP000000000259" ]}, 
...]
```

Then query:

```
UNWIND {param} as pair
MATCH (c:company {company:pair.company})-[r1]->(s:physical_location)-[r5]->(im:im_tkt)
WHERE im.assigned_group_id IN pair.assigned_group_ids
RETURN collect(distinct(im.incident_number)) as im_tkt__incident_number , 
       collect(distinct(im.company)) as im_tkt__company , 
       collect(distinct(im.assigned_support_organization)) as im_tkt__assigned_support_organization , 
       collect(distinct(im.assignee)) as im_tkt__assignee , 
       collect(distinct(im.description)) as im_tkt__description , 
       collect(distinct(im.priority)) as im_tkt__priority , 
       collect(distinct(im.status)) as im_tkt__status , 
       collect(distinct(im.impact)) as im_tkt__impact , 
       collect(distinct(im.entryid_TS1)) as im_tkt__entryid_TS1;
```

for testing you can use

```
UNWIND [{company:"GENERAL ELECTRIC-TELEPRESENCE", assigned_group_ids:[ "SGP000000000259" ]}] as pair
MATCH (c:company {company:pair.company})-[r1]->(s:physical_location)-[r5]->(im:im_tkt)
WHERE im.assigned_group_id IN pair.assigned_group_ids
RETURN ...
```